# Query help and errors

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to implement a query to find the cheapest package to Spain.

I have joined the hotel, excursion, transport, and flight table on package, and summed the totalCost from each of the tables.

I however get a error message when inputting my values, 'Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'package' either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column.' For example

```
  SET IDENTITY_INSERT package ON
           Insert Into package (hotelID, excursionID, transportID, flightID)
           Values (1, 1, 1, 1)
           Insert Into package (hotelID, excursionID, transportID, flightID)
           Values (2, 2, 2, 2)
           Insert Into package (hotelID, excursionID, transportID, flightID)
           Values (3, 3, 3, 3)
           Insert Into package (hotelID, excursionID, transportID, flightID)
           Values (4, 4, 4, 4)
           Insert Into package (hotelID, excursionID, transportID, flightID)
           Values (5, 5, 5, 5)
           Insert Into package (hotelID, excursionID, transportID, flightID)
           Values (6, 6, 6, 6)
           Insert Into package (hotelID, excursionID, transportID, flightID)
           Values (7, 7, 7, 7)
           Insert Into package (hotelID, excursionID, transportID, flightID)
           Values (8, 8, 8, 8)
           Insert Into package (hotelID, excursionID, transportID, flightID)
           Values (9, 9, 9, 9)
           Insert Into package (hotelID, excursionID, transportID, flightID)
           Values (10, 10, 10, 10)

           SET IDENTITY_INSERT package OFF
```

Here is my query

```
      SELECT p.*, (h.totalCost + e.totalCost + t.totalCost, f.totalCost) as    'Total Package Cost' FROM Package p
             INNER JOIN hotel h ON h.hotelId = p.hotelId
             INNER JOIN excursion e ON e.excursionId = p.excursionId
             INNER JOIN transport t ON t.transportId = p.transportId
             INNER JOIN flight f ON f.flightId = p.flightId
      WHERE h.location = 'Spain'
      ORDER BY (h.totalCost + e.totalCost + t.totalCost, f.totalCost) ASC
```

p. is underlined (not matching table name)and h. (Incorrect Syntax near 'h'. Expecting '(', or SELECT.) at the bottom is underlined.

Could someone please fix this for me, thanks!

Comment: `(h.totalCost + e.totalCost + t.totalCost, f.totalCost)` should be `(h.totalCost + e.totalCost + t.totalCost + f.totalCost)`. Notice the comma before f.totalCost should be `+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **1st part:**

Insert into "package" table: Looks like there is identity column in "package"
              and at the very first line of this insert query you're setting "SET IDENTITY_INSERT package ON"
              it means you're trying to insert values in the identity column but not providing the identity column name.

Try to remove the "SET IDENTITY_INSERT package ON"  from first line
       and "SET IDENTITY_INSERT package OFF" from the last line

```
   then execute rest of the insert query.
```

If still getting the error. ***Can you please share the "create table schema of package table"?***

### **2nd part:**

while adding the "totalCost" from different tables remove the "," in between
   your query should look like this:

```
   SELECT p.*, (h.totalCost + e.totalCost + t.totalCost + f.totalCost) as    'Total Package Cost' FROM Package p
             INNER JOIN hotel h ON h.hotelId = p.hotelId
             INNER JOIN excursion e ON e.excursionId = p.excursionId
             INNER JOIN transport t ON t.transportId = p.transportId
             INNER JOIN flight f ON f.flightId = p.flightId
      WHERE h.location = 'Spain'
      ORDER BY (h.totalCost + e.totalCost + t.totalCost + f.totalCost) ASC
```